Error: Invalid CSS after "...m 55% at right
I was writing code in style.scss the following code:
Error: Invalid CSS after "...m 55% at right,": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#2222, #0000) borde"         on line 1939 of sass/c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\desc\user.scss >> ound: radial-gradient(.3rem 55% at right, #2222, #0000) border-box, #fff paddi
background: radial-gradient(.3rem 55% at right, #2222, #0000) border-box, #fff padding-box;

May I ask how to resolve this error?

please try adding commas after 0.3rem and 55%

you code is a valid CSS code, you may have to check your Scss configuration

Hex RGB color codes should have 3 or 6 characters. Try replacing #2222, #0000 with #222, #000.

Convert the color values to the following：
background: radial-gradient(.3rem 55% at right, rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.133), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) border-box, #ffff padding-box;
Thank U！

@YiuChak this answer is wrong, 4 digits is a valid color format. the fact that converting colors works doesn't make this answer correct.

@iorgu MDN is all you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hex-color
